# Mongoose nodejs : find() and populate() calls

Tags: node.js, performance, mongoose

I am wondering which way is the more efficient one ?
Is the findOne().populate() done in one single call to the db ?

```
await collection.findOne({_id: id}).populate('x');
[do stuff]
```

and

```
await collection.findOne({_id: id});
[do stuff]
await collection.populate('x');
```

Comment: You shoud really spend more time reading documentation and trying to understand how things work. Neither the `findOne` nor `populate` function returns a promise so using the `await` keyword is pointless. You obviously haven't read my answer to your previous question which you deleted. If you did you wouldn't have written the same question with obvious mistakes. `collection.populate` and `collection.findOne(..).populate` are 2 different function and they don't accept same parameters.

Comment: @Molda, I've just test what you said : console.log(await PermissionGroup.findOne({ _id: '5ffd6d879c181c3e60b8a63a' }).populate('parents'))

            const data = await PermissionGroup.findOne({ _id: '5ffd6d879c181c3e60b8a63a' });
            await data.populate('parents').execPopulate();
            console.log(data);
The 2 logs give me the exact same thing

Comment: Ok I get it so if I don't add the await it's a query, and with the await it calls the db and get the document (I supposed the exec() function just convert the query to a promise). thx

Comment: Also using the await keyword isn't pointless ;) just test the above code

Comment: The reason it works with await is the fact that the Query object returned by findOne has a  `then` function which `await` automagicaly executes. I wasn't aware it works even without it being a Promise. Also both of the examples you shown makes two separate calls to db so none of them is more efficient.

Comment: @Molda are you sure of that ? I think the await (findOne.populate) is first creating the query, then calling one single time the db and the await findOne ... await data.populate.execPopulate is doing 2 calls

Comment: Yes, one db call for `findOne` another for populating `x` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this package so that you only have to define only your model that you have to populate the data of which field.

```
const nestedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  child: { type: Number, ref: 'Child', autopopulate: true }
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: Can you please accept my answer and upvote to help other community members.